# Problem with video playback Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

Hardware: processor- intel Pentium(R)4 2.8 Ghz, 1GB RAM, Graphics Unknown
switched over from windows xp to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS recently.
Horrible problems with audio and video playback. I am a new user. Please help

Answer (score 1):

if you're switching from an old machine there are probably drivers for your audio and video that you need to install, try looking online for linux drivers that you may need to manually implement.

Or add more to you question with information on your unknown graphics and I may be able to find some drivers for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a program called HARDINFO from the software centre which tells you exactly what your hardware is, then you can find out your graphics and sound card and from there you should be able to find more help to improve graphics and video playback...

Note: if it is a really old machine you may be better running Xubuntu as this will things faster just by not using Unity...